# Hide PHP and apache version when inspecting

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2

In a website made with Wordpress, I'm trying to find out how I hide the version of PHP and Apache2 when I inspect the site.

I think that should be in `000-default.conf`?

I tried to use

```
expose_php = Off
```

in php.ini, but it doesn't work

Comment: It might be in the Apache config too.

Comment: You should post it below as an answer then for others who may be interested. You're allowed to answer your own question :-). And then it can lead to increased reputation points for you.

Comment: Yes I'll  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Apache have `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf` file for these configurations

You need to edit it and set
`ServerTokens` from `OS` to `Prod`

and
`ServerSignature` from `On` to `Off`

Thats the best way to do that, since this applies to all server configuration

If security conf was not enabled yet, just run ( as super user / root ) on terminal:

`a2enconf secutiry; service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

To hide the version of apache, you should add in the server configuration file:

```
ServerTokens Prod 
ServerSignature Off
```